# Beginner on matrix and its rows

Tags: java

I have made a problem to solve with arrays and a matrix. I am beginning to understand how it works but I got the following question regarding the rows of a matrix. Here's this what the problem asks me to do:

a. Write the definition of the method inputArray that prompts the user to input 20 numbers and stores the numbers in alpha.

b. Write the definition of the method doubleArray that initializes the elements of beta to two times the corresponding elements in alpha. Make sure that you prevent the method from modifying the elements of alpha.

c. **Write the definition of the method copyGamma that sets the elements of the first row of inStock to gamma and the remaining rows of inStock to three times the previous rows of inStock. Make sure that you prevent the method from modifying the elements of gamma.**

This is what I've got done:

## Code

```
public class ArrayQuiz {
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
       
        int count = 0;
        int [ ] [ ] inStock = new int [10][14];
        int[ ] alpha = new int[20];
        int[ ] beta = new int[20];
        int[ ] gamma = {11, 13, 15, 17};
        int[ ] delta = {3, 5, 2, 6, 10, 9, 7, 11, 1, 8};
        
        
        alpha(alpha,count);
        beta(beta,count,alpha);
        copyGamma(inStock,gamma,count);
    }
    
    
    public static int alpha(int alpha[],int count){
         count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter 20 numbers:");
      
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            alpha[i] = input.nextInt();
            count = alpha[i];
        }
        return count;
        
}
        
 public static int beta(int beta[], int count, int alpha[]){
     
     for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){
         
         beta[i] = 2*alpha[i];
         count = beta[i];
     }
     
     return count;
 }
        
 public static int copyGamma(int inStock[][], int gamma[], int count){

     for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
             if (i==0)  
             {
             gamma[i] = inStock[i][j];  
            count = gamma [i]; 
             }
             else
             {
                 inStock[i][j] = 3*inStock[i][j];
                count = inStock[i][j];
             }
         }

     }
     
         return count;
     }
 }
```

The output gives no errors plus I haven't made the other method for output yet because I want to make sure that copyGamma is correct. When it means the first row of inStock does it mean the first [] of the matrix and for the remaining does it mean the remaining rows of inStock only? Since gamma has 5 elements inStock rows are left with 5. So that means just multiply i by 3 or the whole matrix? If I'm correct [i] = rows and [j] is columns? I am confused there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. `i` is rows, `j` is columns. However, it looks like you're assigning `gamma[i]` to the value of `inStock[i][j]`, when it looks like you should be assigning it the other way around.